# Git strategie for multiple versions

Tags: git, branching-strategy

I am developing a plugin for another software. Until now, this software was version 2.x.y and my strategie was the following:
I have a **develop branch** on which I am working and which I use to branch of feature-branches until the feature is finished. And I have **release branches** for each x-version of the software. From time to time I do my releases by merging the work of the develop branch into the single release branches. That is fine. The software also grabs the code from the last commits of these release branches to make them available as plugins.
Now, there is version 3.0 of that software. Of course it contains some major changes. I already have a new release branch for that version but I am not sure what to do with my develop branch. Is it fine to adapt it to version 3? Will I be able to still take over new features or enhancements or bugfixes to my release branches from version 2 without problems?
Theoretically, I think this is the way to go but then I would need to make sure not to merge commits I made due to that version change. Is that complicated?
Any other idea how to keep a clean and nice branch structure?

Comment: I would suggest asking this question in a chat room or forum. I am flagging as too broad. Answers would be more opinionated, yet still hold experience and facts. Have you researched anything about "git branch workflows"? I would suggest to start there

Comment: it's a bit hard to find a solution for my case by just searching as I cannot find much for the case the version of the underlying software changes... Anyhow, you might be right that there is not the ONE solution but some personal experiences. Unfortunately, I don't know any other good place to ask such a question...

Comment: you can bring this question up in an SO chat room -- Tavern, (language of your choice) room... Git is a general subject so anyone in any room could help. Or you can ask on a forum (reddit has a git sub I am sure)